# How would I solve this question involving finding a specific derivative?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

"Let $f$ be a function such that $f(1) = 5$ and $f'(1) = -11$.

Find $h'(1)$ for the function $h(x) = f(x)f(x)$."

What I tried to do first was use my intuition and see that $h(1)$ was equal to $25$ and then multiply that by $\frac{-11}5$ to get $-55$ as $h'(1)$. But this was obviously not the correct answer. I then tried to use the product rule to get an expression for $h'(x)$ but I had nothing to work with there in terms of $x$'s and coefficients.

Any help?

Comment: $h'(x) = 2f(x)\times f'(x)$ by the product rule (or just chain rule since $f(x)f(x) = (f(x))^2$).

Comment: Hint: Apply the **Chain Rule** to $h(x)$ and then set $x=1$.

Comment: Since you have asked a number of very similar questions, and have received some answers, what have you done to reflect on what you have learned, so that you are able to do questions like this without having to ask?

Comment: Yes I have learnt a lot! I now know that I can use the same principles to differentiate composite expressions as regular ones. This is what was confusing me. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use chain rule, $$h(x)=f(x)^2$$

then $$h'(x) = 2f(x)f'(x)$$

Suppose that you are not aware of chain rule.

You can also get the same result by product rule.

$$h(x) = f(x)f(x)$$

$$h(x)=f'(x)f(x)+f(x)f'(x)=2f'(x)f(x)$$